# Best hybrid approach to a multi-dimensional array with strong typed indexing

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

I have what amounts to a multi-dimensional array.

```
int[][][] MyValues;
```

What I want is to access the indexes via a strongly typed equivelent, such as an enumeration.  I'm aware that you can get the enumeration values from the Enum type, but it's a bit long winded for my tastes.

I'd rather have a way to Strongly type the indexes.

For example:

```
int CarNumber = MyValues[Racetrack.Daytona][Race.Daytona500][Driver.JGordon];
```

This would, by virtue of it being enum-like, prevent any out of bounds exceptions from being thrown, plus it gives all the indexes a nice human readable meaning.

I've implemented this using a dictionary approach, but it seems kind of heavy handed:

```
Dictionary<Racetrack,Dictionary<Race,<Dictionary<Driver,int>>> =
    new Dictionary<Racetrack,Dictionary<Race,<Dictionary<Driver,int>>>();
```

which I can then access via enums, but I don't really like this approach.  It seems "ugly".

**I'm looking for some alternate methods to represent what is essentially a multi-dimensional array while using human readable indexers, while maintaining type safety (can't accidently use a Driver for a Race, for instance, so simply using consts is not a good approach).**

Any suggestions?

This will be a compile time array (example above is not real, just an illustration) so I don't have to worry about inserts or deletes or other manipulations of the array.  It will stay immutable, both in values, size and layout.

Using a static class with const values is not a good approach either, since it doesn't enforce that only the set of values defined can be passed as indexers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me that you want to use [indexers](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson11.aspx) rather than an array.  Assuming the following enums (Formula 1 based!):

```
public enum Track
{
    Spielberg,
    Adelaide,
    Casablanca,
    Liverpool,
    Melbourne,
    Berlin,
    Sakhir,
}

public enum Constructor
{
    BMW,
    Ferrari,
    McLaren,
    Toyota,
    Williams
}

public enum Driver
{
    Hamilton,
    Kovalainen,
    Raikkonen,
    Nakajima,
    Glock
}
```

the basic structure is as follows:

```
public class Race
{
    int Year { get; set; }
    Track Track { get; set; }
    Driver[] Placings { get; set; }
    public int this[Driver driver] { } // placing by driver
}

public class Results
{
    YearResults this[int index] { }
    DriverResults this[Driver index] { }
    TrackResults this[Track index] { }
    ConstructorResults this[Constructor index] { }
}

public class YearResults
{
    YearDriverResults this[Driver index] { }
}
```

This of course is a partial implementation but you can do some pretty cool things with indexers this way.  Like you can access your information with any combination of values **in any order** (assuming you set up all the intermediate classes).

Its wordier than a multidimensional array or a tuple-keyed Dictionary but I think will give you far more elegant code.

Comment: This is a good point.  Sometimes we get caught up in thinking about the problem as as Hammer solution that we forget it might not be a nail.  Maybe it's a screw or glue.

Comment: Well, no, I don't need Racetrack or Race objects with all sorts of properties or methods.  It's just a collection of numbers with constraints.  But like I said, I hadn't really though about defining them as thir own classes.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a triple `<Racetrack,Race,Driver>` as the key (define your own class) in the `Dictionary`?

If you really need to use an array, I don't think you can do better than wrapping it in a custom class that allows access only using `Racetrack`, `Race`, `Driver` enums.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious question.. Will `List<T>` not work for you?

Comment: List<T> does not allow you to use an enum as an indexer without casts or writing a lot of accessors to get the actual value, and is not type safe.  So no.

Comment: I thought List<T> was type safe? I guess I'm confused.

Comment: It's safe for it's value, not the indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Are the enums reasonably small, with values 0...n? If so, you could use a multi-dimensional array but expose an indexer. Note that the code below uses a rectangular array rather than a jagged array, but you could fairly easily adapt it.

```
// In a static class somewhere. Just a convenience method to check
// whether a value is defined or not. See comment in indexer.
public static void CheckDefined<T>(this T value, String name)
    where T : struct
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name);
    }
}


// Somewhere else...
private static int GetLength<T>() where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Length;
}

private int[,,] array = new int[GetLength<Racetrack>(), 
                                GetLength<Race>(),
                                GetLength<Driver>()];

public int this Car[Racetrack racetrack, Race race, Driver driver]
{
  get
  {
    // If you don't care about just getting an
    // IndexOutOfRangeException, you could skip these three lines.
    racetrack.CheckDefined("racetrack");
    race.CheckDefined("race");
    driver.CheckDefined("driver");
    return array[(int) racetrack, (int) race, (int) driver);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what the "public int this Car" bit is about?  what is the "this" for?

Comment: It's declaring an indexer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the dictionary approach is bad, but it isn't elegant. If you created an alias for your dictionary of dictionary things would look better:

```
using RaceSetup = Dictionary<Racetrack,Dictionary<Race,<Dictionary<Driver,int>>>;
```

Or you could create a class that derived from the dictionary:

```
class RaceSetup : Dictionary<Racetrack,Dictionary<Race,<Dictionary<Driver,int>>>
{}
```

Comment: The larger problem with the dictionary approach is that it creates mess initialization code.  Not a huge problem, but still ugly.